# BeautifulSoup subpages of list with "load more" pagination

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

Quite new here, so apologies in advance. I'm looking to get a list of all company descriptions from https://angel.co/companies to play around with. The web-based parsing tools I've tried aren't cutting it, so I'm looking to write a simple python script. Should I start by getting an array of all the company URLs then loop through them? Any resources or direction would be helpful--I've looked around BeautifulSoup's documentation and a few posts/video tutorials, but I'm getting hung up on simulating the json request, among other things (see here: [Get all links with BeautifulSoup from a single page website ('Load More' feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35849319/get-all-links-with-beautifulsoup-from-a-single-page-website-load-more-feature))

I see a script that I believe is calling additional listings:

```
o.on("company_filter_fetch_page_complete", function(e) {
    return t.ajax({
        url: "/companies/startups",
        data: e,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(t) {
            return t.html ? 
                (E().find(".more").empty().replaceWith(t.html),
                 c()) : void 0
        }
    })
}),
```

Thanks!

Comment: Above this script, if helpful, is:

filters: function(s, l) {
                var c, u, d, h, p, f, g, m, v, y, b, _, w, x, C, A, k, S, N, T, E, D, I, $, P, M;
                return u = new o(s(".currently-showing"),l.data("sort")),
                u.set_data(l.data("init_data")),
                u.render({
                    fetch: !l.data("new")
                }),

Answer (score 6):

The data you want to scrape is dynamically loaded using ajax, you need to do a lot of work to get to the html you actually want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get("https://angel.co/companies").content
    csrf = BeautifulSoup(r).select_one("meta[name=csrf-token]")["content"]
    header["X-CSRF-Token"] = csrf
    ids = s.post("https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data", data={"sort": "signal"}, headers=header).json()
    _ids = "".join(["ids%5B%5D={}&".format(i)  for i in ids.pop("ids")])
    rest = "&".join(["{}={}".format(k,v) for k,v in ids.items()])
    url = "https://angel.co/companies/startups?{}{}".format(_ids, rest)
    rsp = s.get(url, headers=header)
    print(rsp.json())
```

We first need to get a valid csrf-token which is what the initial request does, then we need to post to `https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data`:

[image]

which gives us:

```
{"ids":[296769,297064,60,63,112,119,130,160,167,179,194,236,281,287,312,390,433,469,496,516],"total":908164,"page":1,"sort":"signal","new":false,"hexdigest":"3f4980479bd6dca37e485c80d415e848a57c43ae"}
```

They are the params needed for our get to `https://angel.co/companies/startups` i.e our last request:

[image]

That request then gives us more json which holds the html and all the company info:

```
{"html":"<div class=\" dc59 frs86 _a _jm\" data-_tn=\"companies/results ...........
```

There is way too much to post but that is what you will need to parse.

So putting it all together:

```
In [3]: header = {
   ...:     "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
   ...:     "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
   ...: }

In [4]: with requests.Session() as s:
   ...:         r = s.get("https://angel.co/companies").content
   ...:         csrf = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml").select_one("meta[name=csrf-token]")["content"]
   ...:         header["X-CSRF-Token"] = csrf
   ...:         ids = s.post("https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data", data={"sort": "signal"}, headers=header).json()
   ...:         _ids = "".join(["ids%5B%5D={}&".format(i) for i in ids.pop("ids")])
   ...:         rest = "&".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in ids.items()])
   ...:         url = "https://angel.co/companies/startups?{}{}".format(_ids, rest)
   ...:         rsp = s.get(url, headers=header)
   ...:         soup = BeautifulSoup(rsp.json()["html"], "lxml")
   ...:         for comp in soup.select("div.base.startup"):
   ...:                 text = comp.select_one("div.text")
   ...:                 print(text.select_one("div.name").text.strip())
   ...:                 print(text.select_one("div.pitch").text.strip())
   ...:         
Frontback
Me, now.
Outbound
Optimizely for messages
Adaptly
The Easiest Way to Advertise Across The Social Web.
Draft
Words with Friends for Fantasy (w/ real money)
Graphicly
an automated ebook publishing and distribution platform
Appstores
App Distribution Platform
eVenues
Online Marketplace & Booking Engine for Unique Meeting Spaces
WePow
Video & Mobile Recruitment
DoubleDutch
Event Marketing Automation Software
ecomom
It's all good
BackType
Acquired by Twitter
Stipple
Native advertising for the visual web
Pinterest
A Universal Social Catalog
Socialize
Identify and reward your most influential users with our drop-in social platform.
StyleSeat
Largest and fastest growing marketplace in the $400B beauty and wellness industry
LawPivot
99 Designs for legal
Ostrovok
Leading hotel booking platform for Russian-speakers
Thumb
Leading mobile social network that helps people get instant opinions
AppFog
Making developing applications on the cloud easier than ever before
Artsy
Making all the world’s art accessible to anyone with an Internet connection.
```

As far as the pagination goes, you are limited to 20 pages per day but to get all 20 pages is simply a case of adding `page:page_no` to our form data to get the new params needed, `data={"sort": "signal","page":page}`, when you click load more you can see what is posted:

[image]

So the final code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse(soup):

        for comp in soup.select("div.base.startup"):
            text = comp.select_one("div.text")
            yield (text.select_one("div.name").text.strip()), text.select_one("div.pitch").text.strip()

def connect(page):
    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
        "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    }

    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get("https://angel.co/companies").content
        csrf = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml").select_one("meta[name=csrf-token]")["content"]
        header["X-CSRF-Token"] = csrf
        ids = s.post("https://angel.co/company_filters/search_data", data={"sort": "signal","page":page}, headers=header).json()
        _ids = "".join(["ids%5B%5D={}&".format(i) for i in ids.pop("ids")])
        rest = "&".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in ids.items()])
        url = "https://angel.co/companies/startups?{}{}".format(_ids, rest)
        rsp = s.get(url, headers=header)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(rsp.json()["html"], "lxml")
        for n, p in parse(soup):
            yield n, p
for i in range(1, 21):
    for name, pitch in connect(i):
        print(name, pitch)
```

Obviously what you parse is up to you but everything you see in your browser in the results will be available.

Comment: Padraic, thank you for your thoughtful answer. I'm certain I wouldn't have gotten far without you, considering how I was attacking the problem.

Oddly, I'm consistently getting 383 unique items as output. Any idea why that might be? I believe that page should spit out closer to 900k results.

Comment: @TylerHudson-Crimi, if you click load more 19 times you will see *You reached the maximum of 20 pages per query*

Comment: @TylerHudson-Crimi, what info do you actually want?

Comment: The idea was to train a NN on all these startup descriptions to make a random startup description generator. Now I'm thinking Kramer could be more fun, if Angel List has protected their listings too well.

http://www.imsdb.com/transcripts/Seinfeld-Good-News,-Bad-News.html

Comment: Needed a solution for some web scrapping with load more button, came across this, and the is by far the most descriptive answer I have ever read on this site. I never knew I could do so much and there was so much to do until now. 
Thank you for this answer !