# Scrape dynamically loading page using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm new to the beautifulsoup package. I'm trying to scrape all food recipes and links, and ingredients from https://indianrecipes.com/new_and_popular
The problem is this website only loads more food when scrolled down. I referred this question [Beautifulsoup - scrape webpage - dynamically loading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616908/beautifulsoup-scrape-webpage-dynamically-loading-page), but coudn't make much of it. 
I checked the network tab in inspect element, and found that every time I scroll down, a XHR request is sent

```
api?tm=1565542062069
api?tm=1565542065302
api?tm=1565542073116
api?tm=1565542075617
```

Is it possible to simulate such request in python to extract all food recipes from that page?

Comment: please try and make an attempt at coding this and share where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number in `api?tm=1565542075617` is the epoch timestamp in milliseconds. This may not be necessary for the request.

It is important to see what data the request is sending to which the server will respond. In the XHR request scroll down to `Request Payload` to see the payload.

Below is a Python code which loads `recipes_per_page` number of recipes, after the initial `offset` number of recipes.

```py
import requests

offset = 50
recipes_per_page = 50
data = [{'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': 'recipe.get_trending', 'id': 1, 'params': [offset, recipes_per_page, None, False]}]
response = requests.post('https://indianrecipes.com/api', json=data)

recipes = response.json()[0]['result']['recipes']
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, Very helpful. However i have some doubts. what does response.json() do and how should i go on if i want to load all of response.json() to a beautiful soup object.

Comment: `response` is a `requests.Response` object (see documentation in [here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response)).

`response.json()` assumes that the response is in JSON format, and attempts to parse the `response.content` and return a dictionary of the data.

As the response from the server is in JSON, essentially you can parse it as a Python dictionary. You do not need to use Beautiful Soup, as it is supposed to be used for HTML/XML instead. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use selenium to load javascript from webpage to html
then use scrolling code of selenium

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/sush/Downloads/Compressed/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://indianrecipes.com/new_and_popular')


heights = []
counter = 0
for i in range(1,300):
    bg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body')
    time.sleep(0.1)
    bg.send_keys(Keys.END)
    heights.append(driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight"))
    try :
        bottom = heights[i-16]
    except:
        pass
    if i%16 ==0:
        new_bottom = heights[i-1]
        if bottom == new_bottom:
            break
```

and then use beautifusoup to scrape the data you need by

`soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')`

Answer (score 1):

I made simple script, where you specify number of recipes per page and number of pages you want to scrape. It returns data in JSON format:

```
from itertools import count, islice
import requests
import json

url = 'https://indianrecipes.com/api'
data = {"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"recipe.get_trending","params":[50,50,None,False]}

per_page = 50
num_pages = 2

for i, c in enumerate( islice(count(0, per_page), 0, num_pages), 1):
    print('Page no.{} :'.format(i))
    print('-' * 80)
    data['params'][0] = c
    data['params'][1] = per_page
    json_data = requests.post(url, json=data).json()
    print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Page no.1 :
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{
    "id": 1,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "recipes": [
            {
                "has_video": false,
                "id": 8630002,
                "image_url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/zgZHuLeSg_lKRc66RycpaDoSVMULp3puzoignsoEH40DJBQtOpQi0Ub1L1ET52VFhd3ZUF8r8ZEiD_kEsZNQPloO3_T1KW9sbBE",
                "link": "//indianrecipes.com/recipe/Dahi-Vada_Ad3A",
                "name": "Dahi Vada",
                "rating": 5.0,
                "score": 0.0
            },
            {
                "has_video": false,
                "id": 9330018,
                "image_url": "//lh3.googleusercontent.com/HXd-CD3P0U_v4ItJplGsT5oKZ8mKAAA0AXRsgeOoeLeH4ggvyGRdx-6Y_J1H1EdRLv5De7b5oYqeHkBts4VwIpqBAHNA_OYP8g",
                "link": "//indianrecipes.com/recipe/French-Egg-Casserole_D9aa",
                "name": "French Egg Casserole",
                "rating": 0.0,
                "score": 0.0
            },

...and so on
```