# How to use python to press the “load more” in imdb to get more reviews

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, imdb

I am creating a web crawler now and I want to scrape the user reviews from imdb. It's easy to directly get the 10 reviews and rate from the origin page. For example http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392170/reviews The problem is to get all reviews, I need to press the "load more" so that more reviews will be shown while the url address doesn't change! So I don't know how can I get all the reviews in Python3. What I use now are requests, bs4.

My code now:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_link='http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
html=urlopen(url_link)

content_bs=BeautifulSoup(html)

for b in content_bs.find_all('div',class_='text'):
print(b)

for rate_score in content_bs.find_all('span',class_='rating-other-user-rating'):
print(rate_score)
```

Comment: check out the library called `selenium` for python to do automation tasks, like clicking buttons, etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup subpages of list with "load more" pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799149/beautifulsoup-subpages-of-list-with-load-more-pagination)

Comment: or you can use this request for pagination obtained from chrome network tab, `http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/reviews/_ajax?ref_=undefined&paginationKey=cyi4vu2uxjyffy4ynotlm45pxfmyxwf7xdnnirxpj2oplatil4zhp7rll6tnyzpbo7u5curqcymq2`.
You need to extract the pagination key from the first page and pass it to the above request, to load next page.

Comment: http://www.imdb.com/interfaces/

Answer (score 2):

You can't press the load more button without initiating click event. However, `BeautifulSoup` doesn't have that property. But, what you can do to get the full content is something like what i've demonstrated below. It will fetch you all the `review title` along with `reviews`:

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

main_content = urljoin(url,soup.select(".load-more-data")[0]['data-ajaxurl'])  ##extracting the link leading to the page containing everything available here
response = requests.get(main_content)
broth = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

for item in broth.select(".review-container"):
    title = item.select(".title")[0].text
    review = item.select(".text")[0].text
    print("Title: {}\n\nReview: {}\n\n".format(title,review))
```